# Displaying a realtime counter on a dashboard page

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a messaging app where every message is stored in the real time db.  There is a dashboard to show the total number of messages exchanged so far.

To implement the stat the count of messages is stored for every day and the present day count is updated using a firebase function trigger when a new messages is exchanged.

below is how the data looks

```
stats
     count
        1559260800000 
           messages: 48
        1559347200000
           messages: 6
```

My dashboard html is like below

```
 <div>{{msgCount}}</div><div style="display: none">{{msgCountArr | async}}</div>
```

my .ts

```
 msgCount:number
 msgCountArr: Observable<any[]> 

refreshMessages(){
  this.msgCountArr = this.dataSvc.fetchMsgCount().pipe(
    map((msgs: any) => msgs.map(msgObj => {
          this.msgCount = +this.msgCount + +msgObj.messages
          return msgObj
     }))
  );
}
```

The service looks like below

```
  private msgCountList: AngularFireList<Object>

fetchMsgCount(){
    this.msgCountList = this.db.list<Object>('stats/count', ref => ref.orderByChild("messages"))

    return this.msgCountList.snapshotChanges().pipe(
       map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}))
       )
      ) ;
  }
```

The problem is the the msgCount which basically keeps adding the whole number as i do not know how to reset the counter every time the data is fetched freshly from db.

Also welcome if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: `this.msgCount = +this.msgCount + +msgObj.messages` to be `this.msgCount = msgObj.messages` would resolve this ?

Comment: no it wont. first of all it wont give the sum of messages from all the days.

Comment: What's happening if you change `this.msgCount = +this.msgCount + +msgObj.messages` to `this.msgCount += msgObj.messages` ?

Comment: well it still updates the number to a much large value rather actual